# Custom font in Storyboard from Pod is not showing in the running app

Tags: ios, fonts, uikit, xcode-storyboard

I have created a CococoaPod framework for common UI to be used inside multiple projects. I have assigned Source Sans Pro to UILabels in the storyboard and Font files are added to the CocoaPod framework inside the resource folder.

When any app using this framework runs in the simulator, instead of  Source Sans Pro font, labels are showing Helvetica font.

If I apply font property explicitly in viewDidLoad to UILabel for which Source Sans Pro was set in Storyboard but Helvetica was showing, Source Sans Pro font is shown.

I want to know why appropriate fonts are not showing up from UIStoryboard file coming from Pod framework.

Answer (score -1):

You can set the *`font`* property of  `UILabel` in **storyboard** and as well as in **code**. It depends on how you set your font. If you are trying to set the different font in code than  the one which you already set in Storyboard, It will take the font that you set in Code.

Assume you set the `Sans Pro` to `Label` in `storyboard` and you are trying to set different font `Helvetica` in `viewDidLoad` means, it will take the `Helvetica` only.

It will be good if you consistently follow in any one manner, either in `Storyboard` or in the `Code`.  And you can set the attributes of `UILabel` in it's ***didSet*** property observer

```
@IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel! {
    didSet {
        myLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20) // you can set your custom font as well
        myLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
    }
}
```